# What rx operator to use to call a network function in the middle of a chain?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I finally got the hang of rx. So here comes the questions....

```
    addressSubscription = AppObservable.bindActivity(this, lastKnownLocationObservable
            .flatMap(new Func1<Location, Observable<List<Address>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Address>> call(Location location) {
                    return locationProvider.getGeocodeObservable(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<List<Address>, Address>() {
                @Override
                public Address call(List<Address> addresses) {
                    return addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty() ? addresses.get(0) : null;
                }
            })
            .map(new AddressToStringFunc())

            CALL A OPERATOR HERE THAT WILL SEND SOME RESULTS FROM THIS
            CHAIN OVER THE NETWORK

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

basically if I'm in the middle of a chain what operators are best to make some arbitary call to a function or such and then resume the regularly schedule program....

Comment: you dont need observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) while using AppObservable.bindActivity() , as it observes on the main thered by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some side-effecting stuff, you can use [doXXX](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operators, such as `doOnNext`.

Comment: I was looking at that exact link when this was in focus... nice! so the next operator will pick up the type/Observable from the operator previous to the doOnXXX ?

Comment: Do you mean if the doOnXXX will execute before the Subscriber/Observer? If so, yes.

Comment: Can you give a simple abc example of using this doOnXXX?

Comment: There is an example in this page. You can unfold the RxJava section and find it.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and time.